# What grammar is this: Only once you ... are you interested in

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subject-verb-inversion, negative-polarity-items, only

I came through a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986057/how-to-set-image-name-in-dockerfile#comment126772359_38986676)

> ... Only once you know this are you interested in considering workarounds

I believe I can rephrase it to

"Once you know this, you are interested in considering workarounds"

Or this,

"Once you know this, you *will be* interested in considering workarounds"

Or,

"You will *not* be interested in considering workarounds *until* you know this"

I realise that it kinda make more sense to me when I change it from present tense ("are") to future tense ("will").

My question is, what grammar is this exactly? How can I learn more about it. Because this is definitely not the first time I encounter this style and I am just curious.

Super grateful.

Comment: Welcome to our site. Please read through the duplicates I've linked to. If together those do not answer your question, feel free to say so.

Comment: Those duplicates are helpful. Thanks!